# can you update or remove old charts in excel using apache poi?

Tags: apache-poi

Can you update graph data like add new series to existing graph ? or remove old graph all together ?

my current code for creating a chart:

```
Drawing drawing = reportSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20, 40);

            Chart chart = ((XSSFDrawing) drawing).createChart(anchor);
            ChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
            legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT);
            LineChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();
            ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
            leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

            ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(reportSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, NUM_OF_ROW - 1, 0, 0));

            for(int i=1; i<NUM_OF_COL; i++){
                ChartDataSource<Number> ys = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(reportSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, NUM_OF_ROW - 1, i, i));
                LineChartSeries series1 = data.addSeries(xs, ys);
                series1.setTitle(weekName);
            }

            chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
```

I am re-drawing the chart everytime, can update an exisiting chart ?